# Unable to install SonarQube v7.9.1 on windows 10

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to install SonarQube 7.9.1 in my windows 10 machine. And when I run StartSonar.bat on the command line, I get the below error:

> Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/yaml/YAMLParser”.

This is a fresh install and never had any previous version of SonarQube. As a prerequisite I installed JDK as below:

> openjdk version “11” 2018-09-25
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)

Is there any other prerequisite other than JDK to be installed? Can I know any other reason?

These are the logs:

> 2019.09.24 16:57:23 INFO app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\Team\Sonarqube\temp
>   2019.09.24 16:57:23 INFO app[o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
>   2019.09.24 16:57:23 INFO app[o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key=‘es’, ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [C:\Team\Sonarqube\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Team\Sonarqube\temp -XX:ErrorFile=…/logs/es_hs_err_pid%p.log -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=C:\Team\Sonarqube\elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=C:\Team\Sonarqube\temp\conf\es -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
>   2019.09.24 16:57:23 INFO app[o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
>   2019.09.24 16:57:23 INFO app[o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
>   2019.09.24 16:57:23 INFO app[o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
>   Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/yaml/YAMLParser
>   at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentType$3.xContent(XContentType.java:94)
>   at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory.xContent(XContentFactory.java:135)
>   at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings$Builder.loadFromStream(Settings.java:1128)
>   at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings$Builder.loadFromPath(Settings.java:1112)
>   at org.elasticsearch.node.InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareEnvironment(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:100)
>   at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.createEnv(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:95)
>   at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
>   at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124)
>   at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
>   at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:116)
>   at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLParser
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>   … 11 more

Comment: Try using the wrapper.java.command setting in wrapper.conf.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I tried what you mention and did not help. I have set environmental variable "JAVA_HOME". From the logs what I understand is that the JVM was started and it is failing in Elastic search/Netty4Plugin/YAMLGenerator .